# titanium mobile:retrieve row title from tableview and its display in next window issue

Tags: titanium-mobile

Hello friends,

I am developing an app which **displays category types using custom cell in tableview**  and then selects a row its go to detail which selected category type but I'm facing a problem that is **I can't get row title in the next window**. So please give me idea how to solve it.

```
Ti.include('PlacesTypeCustomCell.js');
var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var tableData = [];

// Create table
var tableData = new PlacesTypeCells();

var myTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView
({
    data:tableData,
    top:45,
    height:368

});
currentWindow.add(myTableView);

myTableView.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    var index = e.index;
    Ti.API.log('Row at index:'+index);
    Titanium.App.Properties.setInt('index',index);

    v//get each row title from tableview
var pageTitle = Titanium.App.Properties.setString('title',e.rowData.pageTitle);
Ti.API.log('Page Title:'+pageTitle);

var pageAddress = Titanium.App.Properties.setString('address',e.rowData.pageAddress);
Ti.API.log('Page Address:'+pageAddress);

    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow
    ({
        url:'PlacesList.js',
        title:'Place List'
    });

    Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});
});


//Custom Cell PlacesTypeCustomCell



    var tableData=[];

    var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";    
    url = url + "location=" + lat + ',' + lon;
    url = url + "&radius=" + radius;
    url = url + "&name=" + name;
    url = url + "&sensor=" + sensor;
    url = url + "&key=" + key;

    Ti.API.info(url);
    // Sets the HTTP request method, and the URL to get data from
    loader.open("GET",url);
    // Create our HTTP Client and name it "loader"
    // Runs the function when the data is ready for us to process
    loader.onload = function() 
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.log(obj);    
        var results = obj.results;
        Ti.API.log(results);


        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            categoryName = obj.results[i].name; 
            reference = obj.results[i].reference;
            Ti.API.log('Refernce:'+reference);

            getDetailsData();

            // Create a row and set its height to auto
            row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'78'});

            var placeImage =  Titanium.UI.createImageView
            ({
                image:'../iphone/appicon.png',
                width:70,
                height:50,
                top:12,
                left:5
            });

            // Create the label to hold the tweet message
            var nameLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                //text:name,
                left:80,
                top:5,
                height:'auto',
                width:200,
                textAlign:'left',
                font:{fontSize:12}
            });

            // Create the label to hold the tweet message
            addressLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                left:80,
                top:25,
                height:'auto',
                width:200,
                textAlign:'left',
                font:{fontSize:14}
            });

            var arrowImage = Ti.UI.createImageView
            ({
                image:'../iphone/appicon.png',
                width:20,
                height:20,
                left:280,
                top:30
            });

            nameLabel.text = categoryName;

            getDetailsData(addressLabel);

            row.add(placeImage);
            row.add(nameLabel);
            row.add(addressLabel);
            row.add(arrowImage);

            tableData[i] = row;

            //set page title for each row
            row.pageTitle = tableData[i];
            row.pageAddress = tableData[i];
        }

        tableView.setData(tableData);

    };

//PlaceList.js
var currentWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
//retrive index value
var index = Titanium.App.Properties.getInt('index');
Ti.API.log('NextView Index:'+index);

var title = Titanium.App.Properties.getString('title');
Ti.API.log('CheckInView Title:'+title);

var address = Titanium.App.Properties.getString('address');
Ti.API.log('CheckInView Address:'+address);
```

[image]

**My problem is that I can't get row title in next window but I get index value of that row so please give me idea how to fetch it.**

Comment: Where are you setting the row title while creation?

Comment: I am just setString in myTableView.addEventListene method where I  can setting the row title?? plz help

Comment: please online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this after the following line:

> var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'});

Set a title as property of your row like this:

> row.pageTitle = tableData[i];

And in click event you can get this property like this:

```
myTableView.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{ 
   e.rowData.pageTitle
}
```

Comment: plz see my update screen shot and I want to get name and address separately in next window give me idea. plz chat with me

Comment: Just pass those as well as a new property, like i did in the answer.

Comment: rowrow.pageTitle = tableData[i];
row.pageAddress = tableData[i]; and its return me in nextwindow [object TiUITableViewRow] [object TiUITableViewRow] so how can i set in label

Comment: Where is name and adress stored? In  tableData[i] ?

Comment: let us http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: whenever r u frre plz online in chat?

Comment: hello Muhammad I send a mail about my issue so please give me solution

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz onilne chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav

Comment: plz online in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7529/discussion-between-muhammad-zeeshan-and-nikunj-r-jadav